# Change directory in pipe line bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

My folder structure:

```
-backend
-frontend
```

My reactapp is placed in `frontend` directory.

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - yarn install
          - yarn test
          - yarn build
```

This one fails. How do I go to the frontend-directory to run this?

Comment: Do you have the github repo since I need the same pipelines setup? Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Bitbucket Pipeline run in one bitbucket cloud server.

So, similar as using a local command line interface, you can navigate using comands like `cd, mkdir`.

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - cd frontend
          - yarn install
          - yarn test
          - yarn build
          - cd ../ #if you need to go back
    #Then,probably you will need to deploy your app, so you can use:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST
```

If you need to test syntax of your yml file, [try here](https://bitbucket-pipelines.prod.public.atl-paas.net/validator)

Comment: Do you have the github repo since I need the same pipelines setup for Wordpress? Thanks

Comment: I have one private repo for my PHP website, for wordpress this code above work with some changes, you can try this. Let me know if you can't do, maybe i can help you.